# How can I keep the Tab title text fixed, during movement through separate split panes/panels?

Tags: vim-windows, tabbed-user-interface

Generally, I only use split panes inside of a Tab when using plugins like NerdTree, TagBar, and Codi, or when opening up helptags with `:help`. When I enter one of these panes, the Tab title text changes from the "primary" file name to `__TagBar__.1`, `NERD_tree_1`, or `No Name`, for the respective plugins, or something like `map.txt`.

How can I force `Vim` to **freeze the original Tab title text**, so that entering one of these panels will not change it? This default behavior becomes very annoying when you have multiple tabs open, and it becomes hard to tell which document is where.

FYI I have **[TabLine](https://github.com/mkitt/tabline.vim)** installed, but I believe this is also a problem without it.

Comment: You can use the [`'tabline'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27tabline%27) setting to control the display of the tab title. In fact, that is *all* that plugin you linked to does! There is a "simplistic example that results in a tab pages line that resembles the default" in the docs, which you can modify to *not* change the tab label when the new buffer is of a certain `buftype`.

Comment: Can you copy/point me to that example? Can't seem to find it.

Comment: Follow the `setting-tabline` tag in the "See setting-tabline for more info." ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out a method by hijacking the content of the **[Tabline](https://github.com/mkitt/tabline.vim/blob/master/plugin/tabline.vim)** plugin. The function simply labels each tab by the first name in the list of open buffers with `filetype`s not in the list `["nerdtree","tagbar","codi","help"]`.

Just place the lines below anywhere in your `.vimrc`:

```
function! Tabline()
  let s = ''
  for i in range(tabpagenr('$'))
    let tab = i + 1
    let buflist = tabpagebuflist(tab)
    let bufignore = ['nerdtree', 'tagbar', 'codi', 'help']
    for b in buflist
      let buftype = getbufvar(b, "&filetype")
      if index(bufignore, buftype)==-1 "index returns -1 if the item is not contained in the list
        let bufnr = b
        break
      elseif b==buflist[-1]
        let bufnr = b
      endif
    endfor
    let bufname = bufname(bufnr)
    let bufmodified = getbufvar(bufnr, "&mod")
    let s .= '%' . tab . 'T'
    let s .= (tab == tabpagenr() ? '%#TabLineSel#' : '%#TabLine#')
    let s .= ' ' . tab .':'
    let s .= (bufname != '' ? '['. fnamemodify(bufname, ':t') . '] ' : '[No Name] ')
    if bufmodified
      let s .= '[+] '
    endif
  endfor
  let s .= '%#TabLineFill#'
  return s
endfunction
set tabline=%!Tabline()
```